# Inheritance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, inheritance

My code :

```
dbManager = coreDataStack.managedContext as! DbManager
```

`DbManger` class:

```
class DbManager: NSManagedObjectContext {

}
```

Could you tell me what i missed? `coreDataStack` is not nil, `managedContext` is not nil but app crashes on the casting.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance of the base class, `NSManagedObjectContext`, and you're trying to cast it to its subclass `DbManager`, but it isn't one.

Inheritance involves an is-a relationship. A `DbManager` instance *is an* `NSManagedObjectContext`, but the reverse does not apply.

Put another way, say you have a class called `Car`. Then you subclass and expand it to create a `RocketCar` class. You can't just instantiate a `Car` and transform it into a `RocketCar` using a cast.

Comment: Oh now i understand. Is any way to pass this reference ?

Comment: @Laxsion12 [The documentation for NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) has a section on subclassing that begins with "You are strongly discouraged from subclassing NSManagedObjectContext," so I really don't think you want to. I believe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want have DbManager Which will have inside other DbManagers (NSObject subclasses) 1 DbManager = 1 Entity in db. Its just a Entity manager with save , select etc methods and you have access to all this managers through NSManageObjectContex subclass manager